# Get image alt, add as parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm doing some CSS and I'm not great with JavaScript. However I'm not allowed to edit any of the plugin files, so I thought I could use some JavaScript to solve my issue of missing unique classes.

I just want to take the `alt=""` HTML attribute from an image and apply it as `class=""` HTML attribute to its parent `<a>` element.

So instead of:

```
<div class="wrapper-class">    
    <a class="img-parent">
        <img alt="image 1" src="">
    </a>    
    <a class="img-parent">
        <img alt="image 2" src="">
    </a>    
    <a class="img-parent">
        <img alt="image 3" src="">
    </a>    
</div>
```

I need:

```
<div class="wrapper-class">    
    <a class="img-parent image-1">
        <img alt="image 1" src="">
    </a>    
    <a class="img-parent image-2">
        <img alt="image 2" src="">
    </a>    
    <a class="img-parent image-3">
        <img alt="image 3" src="">
    </a>    
</div>
```

Here's the pseudocode I would like to do:

```
(1) $ Function = ('**.wrapper-class**')
(2) IF (**this**) contains **img**
(3) GET image **alt value**
(4) if (this) contains ('**a**')
(6) Replace **alt** value empty space with - and apply **alt** value to **a** element as class
(7) else = do nothing
```

How can I do something like this?

Comment: On click? On pageload?

Comment: The css class is for styling the element so onload would be best

Comment: Can you get by with just styling the `<img>`? You can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to match on the `alt` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me say that it's not a very good idea to use alt attribute value and use it as class name. Assuming the alt attribute gets generated from filename, the filename permits characters which are illegal to use as CSS class names.

I.e.: *picture+label.jpg* and *picture.with.label.jpg* are perfectly valid filenames. Let's say the gallery strips the file extension at least, you get *picture+label* and *picture.with.label* as alt attributes both of which cannot be used as class names because dot and plus sign have special meanings in CSS selectors.

So to be safe, you might want to do some escaping of the value before using it as class name.

I suggest:

```js
(function addClasses() {
    $('.wrapper-class img').each(function (i, image) {
        var imageElem = $(image);
        var altValue = imageElem.attr("alt"); // Use .attr, not .prop as alt is always a string.
        if (!altValue)
            return; // either skip to next if image has no alt value or use some default value
        
        // Replace invalid characters here, i.e. using Regular expression
        altValue = altValue.replace(/[^a-z0-9\-_]/gi, "_");

        // .closest() allows the image to be wrapped in another element/s beside the link
        imageElem.closest("a.img-parent").addClass(altValue);
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-class">
  <a class="img-parent"><img alt="image-1"></a>
  <a class="img-parent"><img alt="image-2"></a>
  <a class="img-parent"><img alt="image-3"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. And no worries, All alt attributes are empty until entered manually. Only title attributes are automatically filled in from the file name on our system.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple `each` would do it, assuming all `.img-parent`s have the `img` in question as their only child:

```js
$('.img-parent').each(function() {
  this.classList.add(this.children[0].alt.replace(/ /g, '-'));
});
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-class">

  <a class="img-parent">
    <img alt="image 1" src="">
  </a>

  <a class="img-parent">
    <img alt="image 2" src="">
  </a>

  <a class="img-parent">
    <img alt="image 3" src="">
  </a>

</div>
```

(Also, it's called "[psuedocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)")

Comment: This worked amazing! The only issue i have now which i didnt foresee is some image alt values have spaces like alt="im a flower"

Is there any way to make the class show up as "im-a-flower" instead of "im a flower" which is giving me multiple classes.

Comment: Just replace spaces with dashes with `.replace`

Comment: I updated my question and sudo code to include the issue commented above.

Answer (score 0):

This should find images and add alt attribute to `<a>` parent's class

```js
$('.wrapper-class img').each(function(){
  $(this).parent('a').addClass($(this).prop('alt').replace(/\s/g,'-'));
  //$(this).parent('a').addClass($(this).prop('alt'));
});
console.log($('.wrapper-class').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-class">

  <a class="img-parent">
    <img alt="im a flower" src="">
  </a>

  <a class="img-parent">
    <img alt="image-2" src="">
  </a>

  <a class="img-parent">
    <img alt="image-3" src="">
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only issue i have now which i didnt foresee is some image alt values have spaces like alt="im a flower"

Is there any way to make the class show up as "im-a-flower" instead of "im a flower" which is giving me multiple classes.

Comment: I updated my question and sudo code to include the issue commented above.

Comment: Check my answer again